# Python Анализ содержания строки и поиск ключевых совпадений

Tags: python, nlp, анализ, строки

Способ отфильтровать полезный контент в строке от команды в этой строке. Например: "найди в интернете сколько живут колибри". Результат: "найди в интернете" - команда, "сколько живут колибри" - контент. Важное условие - в команде из строки может быть опечатка, так что просто вырезать команду через split не получится. Пробовал использовать fuzzywuzzy, но эта штука дико непредсказуемая, а норм описания, соответствующего действительности так и не нашел.

Также имеется база команд, в виде джейсона. Одну из этих команд и надо найти в строке

Есть идеи как это можно провернуть?

Comment: Опечатки могут быть в словах или с пробелами тоже могут быть проблемы? Покажите вашу базу команд. Ну или хотя бы примеры. Есть кое-какие идеи. Да, и команда может быть только в начале строки или в любом месте?

Answer (score 0):

Если опечатки только в самих словах могут быть, а пробелы правильно стоят, и если команда всегда идёт впереди, то всё довольно просто:

- сортируете список команд по количеству слов в команде (в порядке убывания) - это чтобы случайно не "распознать" короткую команду там, где на самом деле длинная
- идёте циклом по этому списку
- отрезаете от фразы столько первых слов, сколько слов в команде
- проверяете через `fuzzywuzzy` процент совпадения, если он больше скольки-то, то всё - нашли, иначе продолжаете цикл

Вариант последнего пункта на случай, если нет коротких команд, совпадающих первыми словами с длинными командами (при опечатке где-то в конце команды будет выбрана короткая команда, а не длинная этим способом):

- вычисляете процент совпадения `fuzzywuzzy`, добавляете в специальный список кортеж `(скор, длина команды)`
- берёте максимум от этого списка, в нём будет искомая длина команды